# Creating a SQL database UI in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sql-server, database, user-interface, sharepoint-2013

I have never worked with SharePoint before, ever. I now have the database in SQL with all the stored procedures in place. Where do I even start if I want to create an interface for it in SharePoint 2013. I spent a week looking through all kinds of tutorials but none of them seem to talk about what I need to do. I am absolutely utterly lost. I am an intern in the Finance department and absolutely no one here can help me or give me any guidance. Please tell me where do I even start.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe,  "external content type" and business connectivity services could help you. You can find more information in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mind_talks/archive/2012/04/03/sharepoint-list-from-sql-server-table-external-content-type-with-sharepoint-designer.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee557243%28v=office.14%29.aspx.

It works with queries (I assume store procedures return tables)

Comment: Yeah.. I saw this... this is not quite enough cause I need to have input fields and drop down menus which are going to pass parameters to the stored procedures... So I need something more vast =/

Answer (score 0):

One more article how to do it - http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=794

Answer (score 0):

As far as the overall approach do you think I should stick to the idea of using webparts and connecting external sources to them? Also I am not sure how to customize them, add buttons, etc., etc.

In other words I did the business connectivity things and I know how to display a table from SQL in Sharepoint, but I am not sure where I should move on from here and what I should google...